# MS Access Rollback error handling Rollback

Tags: error-handling, ms-access-2013, rollback

In my Programm I have a fucntion that does three thing: It makes several inserts in some tables, it creates a pdf document and it sends an e-mail with the created document in the attachment. I have a problem resolving the error handling.

```
    DAO.DBEngine.BeginTrans
    On Error GoTo failed
    
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblClaimStatus ( ClaimID, ClaimStatusTypeID, UserID) " & _
        "VALUES (" & claimId & ", 2," & CurrentUserId & ");", dbFailOnError
    CurrentDb.Execute "Insert INTO tblClaimPartner (ClaimId, OriginalDeadline, NachfristDeadline) " & _
        "VALUES (" & claimId & ", '" & Me.OriginalDeadlineTextbox & "', '" & Me.NewDeadlineTextbox & "');", dbFailOnError
    
    WriteGraceDocument (claimId)
    SendEmail (claimId)
    DAO.DBEngine.CommitTrans
```

The problem is I want to be able to rollback the SQL-transaction, if anything fails. But I also need the not yet committed data in the Subs WriteGraceDocuement and SendEmail.

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Let your functions return *success* or *no success*:

```vb
DAO.DBEngine.BeginTrans

' Validate the values before attempting to insert these.
Success = ValidateInserts(claimId, 2, CurrentUserId, Me!OriginalDeadlineTextbox.Value, Me!NewDeadlineTextbox.Value)

If Success Then    
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblClaimStatus ( ClaimID, ClaimStatusTypeID, UserID) " & _
        "VALUES (" & claimId & ", 2," & CurrentUserId & ");", dbFailOnError
    CurrentDb.Execute "Insert INTO tblClaimPartner (ClaimId, OriginalDeadline, NachfristDeadline) " & _
        "VALUES (" & claimId & ", '" & Me.OriginalDeadlineTextbox & "', '" & Me.NewDeadlineTextbox & "');", dbFailOnError
End If
    
If Success Then
    Success = WriteGraceDocument(claimId)
End If
If Success Then
    Success = SendEmail (claimId)
End If

If Success Then
    DAO.DBEngine.CommitTrans
Else
    DAO.DBEngine.RollBack
End If
```